# Using Armadillo Sparse Matrices in MPI

Tags: c++, mpi, armadillo

I am trying to initialise Armadillo sparse matriix [sp_mat](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat) within MPI as follows:

```
if(rank==0)
{  // some code for locations, values
    sp_mat X(locations,values)
}
// this is where I want to use X
if(rank==0)
   some_fun(X)
```

As you can see, Armadillo constructor is local to the `if block` and as such can not use it after `if block`.
Putting the same question in another way:

```
extern sp_mat X
if(rank==0)
{  // some code for locations, values
    sp_mat X(locations,values)
}
// this is where I want to use X
 if(rank==0)
   some_fun(X)
```

Using `extern sp_mat X` before `if block` also does not help (I got undefined reference error).
How can I initialise X and reuse it afterward?

Comment: did it work? from earlier question

Comment: No. It did not work.

Comment: The **declaration** of `X` is local to the if branch, therefore you cannot use `X` outside of that branch. Read some C++ tutorial/book...

Comment: How about using `extern` in the declaration? Can you explain me why is that error?

Comment: `extern` only means that a variable is defined somewhere else (e.g., in some linked library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (smart) pointers:

```
std::unique_ptr<sp_mat> X; // or std::shared_ptr<sp_mat> or sp_mat*
if (rank == 0) {
   // some code for locations and values     
   X = std::unique_ptr<sp_mat>(new sp_mat(locations, values));
}
...
if (rank == 0)
   some_fun(*X);
```

Comment: FYI, I am aware of MPI Basics. Now my comment on the 1st solution: using empty constructor `sp_mat X` is not allowed for `batch  insertion` through the use of locations and values (see [sp_mat](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat)). I need to look at your 2nd solution. To ans your question, I want to load X for only `root` process and I know that `X` is only local to root. This is what I want.

Comment: @chandresh Ok, I was confused, since you fill values of `X` only in the root process, but then you use `X` in all processes (via `some_fun()`).

Comment: No, I am using `X` in root process only.

Comment: You are not, at least in your presented code (you use `X` outside of the if branch). Please, try to show us here the code that you really use, considering MWE (minimal working example).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Infact use of `sp_mat *` is shorter to use rather than `unique_ptr`

Comment: You're welcome. Just I would argue that `sp_mat*` is shorter, since you need to manually free the allocated memory by using `delete`. With `unique_ptr`, it is done automatically for you, which is why smart pointers exist.

Comment: I second that. BTW, Do you know why `extern` did not work in this case?

Comment: Because `extern` only means that the variable is defined somewhere else (e.g., in a linked library). Thus a compiler complains about missing this definition.

Comment: What if I put `extern` in header file and define `sp_mat X` in the if block as shown above?

Comment: If you define `X` in the if block, you won't be able to use `X` outside of this block. Look at some scoping rules for C++.

Comment: OK. I just  tested this but hard luck.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using pointer tricks, the much cleaner [`std::move()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) from C++11 can be used:

```
sp_mat X;

if(rank==0)
{  // some code for locations, values
    X = std::move( sp_mat(locations,values) );
}
```